# How to create 2 tables from 1 table in mySQL and both the new created tables are interlinked?

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

```
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `plan`;
CREATE TABLE `plan` (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        `name` VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
        plan_id INT NOT NULL,
        features VARCHAR (25), 
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
INSERT INTO `plan` (`name`,plan_id,features)
VALUES('No Plan',0,NULL),('Basic',1000,NULL),('Silver',1000,'100'),('Gold',1000,'100,200'),('Platinum',1000,'100,200,300'),('Silver/TB',1000,'100,300'),('Lot Plan',2000,NULL)
-- SELECT * FROM `plan`;

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `plana`;
CREATE TABLE `plana` (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        plan_id INT NOT NULL,
        `name` VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `planb`;
CREATE TABLE `planb` (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        plana_id INT NOT NULL,
        feature_id INT NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

> Note: `planb` table will either have no entry or multiple entries for every row in `plana` table.

Comment: Your final structure is incorrect. You must normalize features storing. Final structure must be `plan_ids` - 1:N - `plan_names` - M:N - `features` (4 tables).

Comment: It would be useful if you shared some additional info on what you are trying to achieve here, otherwise we can only assume your intentions.